# Get Day of The Week from Date Range in Javascript

Tags: javascript

how do I save the day of the week to array from a given date range. For example, from 8/23/2021 to 12/11/2021, I would like to get the dates that are Mondays and save these dates to an array? Thanks

Comment: There is a good library: momentJs that is useful for anything to do with date/Time, you might save yourself reinventing the wheel.. https://momentjs.com/ Otherwise you can use the getDay - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay?retiredLocale=it

Comment: @Pogrindis momentJs is not generally recommended anymore (even by the project itself), but it has a useful recommendations page of modern alternatives: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/-project-status/recommendations/

Comment: Good to know, old habits die hard I guess.

Answer (score 0):

So you can use the [getDay](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay?retiredLocale=it) method.

Given your date:

```
var someday = new Date('8/23/2021');
```

using the `getDay` against the `someday` will return the day of the week index. 1 in this case.

*Edit (Side-note): Looks like Sunday is the start of the week for JS*

We can pass some options to get the proper long day and formatting.

```
var long_day = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US', { weekday: 'long'}).format(someday);
```

This will return, Monday. You could save it when its 1/Monday, up to you.

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/pjyeaw8g/)